# How to express "the minimum integral type larger than T"?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, idioms

Suppose I have an integer type T (signed or unsigned). I want to refer (at compile time) to the smallest integer type (signed or unsigned) which can hold, say, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` plus 1 (in the non-overflowing sense, I mean).

What's a nice generic way of doing that?

Comment: ammm... isn't it the unsigned integer type whose twice the size of `T`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I think OP means the smallest of all types that can hold that value. i.e. if you have a choice between uint32_t and uint64_t, pick uint32_t.

Comment: @Borgleader That makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: If `T` is unsigned (ie `std::numeric_limits<T>::min() == 0`), then it's the signed (or unsigned) type that is twice the size of `T`, otherwise, it is the `unsigned` integer type of the same size than `T`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Typo; I meant "smallest".

Comment: @DavidHaim: I'm not at all sure that's guaranteed. Luckily I've been able to avoid making that assumption...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unsigned types, this does the trick:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned size_in_bits() { return  sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT; }

template <typename T>
using least_larger_uint_t = 
    typename boost::uint_t<size_in_bits<T>() + 1>::least;
```

And if we want something to work for any integer type:

```
template <typename T, int NumBits>
using boost_integer_type = 
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_unsigned<T>::value,
        boost::uint_t<NumBits>, 
        boost::int_t<NumBits>
    >::type;

template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned size_in_bits() { return sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT; }

template <typename T>
using least_larger_integral_t = 
    typename boost_integer_type<T, size_in_bits<T>() + 1>::least;
```

See the [documentation for Boost.Integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html) for details on `int_t<N>` and `uint_t<N>`.

Answer (score 2):

You might specify integers by required size and select accordingly:

```
#include <cstdint>

namespace Detail {
    template <std::size_t> struct integer_of_size_undefined {};
    template <> struct integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int8_t)> {
        typedef int8_t type;
    };
    template <> struct integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int16_t)> {
        typedef int16_t type;
    };
    template <> struct integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int32_t)> {
        typedef int32_t type;
    };
    template <> struct integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int64_t)> {
        typedef int64_t type;
    };

    template <std::size_t> struct unsigned_integer_of_size_undefined {};
    template <> struct unsigned_integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int8_t)> {
        typedef uint8_t type;
    };
    template <> struct unsigned_integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int16_t)> {
        typedef uint16_t type;
    };
    template <> struct unsigned_integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int32_t)> {
        typedef uint32_t type;
    };
    template <> struct unsigned_integer_of_size_undefined<sizeof(int64_t)> {
        typedef uint64_t type;
    };
}

template <std::size_t N>
struct integer_of_size {
    typedef typename Detail::integer_of_size_undefined<N>::type type;
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct unsigned_integer_of_size {
    typedef typename Detail::unsigned_integer_of_size_undefined<N>::type type;
};


#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct next_integer {
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_signed<T>::value,
        typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type,
        typename integer_of_size<2*sizeof(T)>::type>::type
        type;
};

int main ()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<next_integer<std::int16_t>::type, uint16_t>::value,
        "Should be a unsigned 16 bit");
    static_assert(std::is_same<next_integer<std::uint16_t>::type, int32_t>::value,
        "Should be a signed 32 bit");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the standard guarantee there can be no integral type of size 3, or 6?

Comment: ... in that case, I don't want _my_ code to be the one making that assumption, I would rather rely on what's already expressed in the standard library (or at most Boost, as in my answer) for that knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using the types from `cstdint`:

```
template <typename T>
struct next_type {
    typedef error_type type;
};

template <>
struct next_type<std::int32_t> {
    typedef std::uint32_t type;
}

template <>
struct next_type<std::uint32_t> {
    typedef std::int64_t type;
}

// Add more...
```

Adding the specializations for each type. Then use it:

```
typename next_type<T>::type
```

So if you are using the maximum possible type already, you are getting the `error_type`, which you must somehow define what it is yourself, otherwise it takes the specialization.

It would perhaps be better to use the `_least` types from `cstdint`, like `std::int_least32_t` goes to `std::uint_least32_t`.

Comment: But how do you know which type is bigger?  For instance there is no guarantee that a `int` has a larger max than a `unsigned short`.

Comment: I think using the types from <cstdint> should take care of that, otherwise you are right.

Comment: Maybe even using the _least types from it, for example int_least8_t to uint_least8t

Comment: Yes you would have to limit it to the fixed width types.

Comment: @Byteventurer: I think Boost has already done most of this work for me, see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to work well on every integer type, you can embed this in a trait built in several steps. We begin by mapping integral types with their bit size:

```
#define CREATE_SIGNED_META_OBJ(x) template <>\
    struct signed_integer_type<x> {\
        typedef int##x##_t type;\
    };

#define CREATE_UNSIGNED_META_OBJ(x) template <>\
    struct unsigned_integer_type<x> {\
        typedef uint##x##_t type;\
    };

template <std::size_t length>
struct signed_integer_type;

template <std::size_t len>
struct unsigned_integer_type;

CREATE_SIGNED_META_OBJ(8)
CREATE_SIGNED_META_OBJ(16)
CREATE_SIGNED_META_OBJ(32)
CREATE_SIGNED_META_OBJ(64)

CREATE_UNSIGNED_META_OBJ(8)
CREATE_UNSIGNED_META_OBJ(16)
CREATE_UNSIGNED_META_OBJ(32)
CREATE_UNSIGNED_META_OBJ(64)
```

Then, the trait in itself can be built. We want to apply our dichotomy on the value of the assertion `std::numeric_limits<Int>::min() == 0`...

```
template <typename Int, bool>
struct get_smallest_for_max_plus_one;

template <typename Int>
struct get_smallest_for_max_plus_one<Int, true> {
    typedef typename signed_integer_type<2*sizeof(Int)*8>::type type;
};

template <typename Int>
struct get_smallest_for_max_plus_one<Int, false> {
    typedef typename unsigned_integer_type<sizeof(Int)*8>::type type;
};

template <typename Int>
using get_fittest_int_type = get_smallest_for_max_plus_one<Int, std::numeric_limits<Int>::min() == 0>;
```

Now we can use directly `get_fittest_int_type` with any integral integer... Running examples can be found on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75866e4db98ced5f).

For consistency's sake though, I guess you want to keep the `signed` or `unsigned` property... If this is the case, you could just replace the specializations of `get_smallest_for_max_plus_one` with the following:

```
// Unsigned type, we want to get the smallest unsigned type that can hold max + 1
template <typename Int>
struct get_smallest_for_max_plus_one<Int, true> {
    typedef typename unsigned_integer_type<2*sizeof(Int)*8>::type type;
};

// Signed type, we want the smallest signed type that can hold max + 1
template <typename Int>
struct get_smallest_for_max_plus_one<Int, false> {
    typedef typename signed_integer_type<2*sizeof(Int)*8>::type type;
};
```

Comment: ... but does the C++ standard actually guarantee there can be no integer types of size 3 or 6?

Comment: @einpoklum Your doubts seem legit to me, I didn't check this fact. I just provided a minimal example with common integer types. Your solution based on boost seems more versatile in that regard!